# Core data - implementing a custom to one relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am not sure if this is a dumb question:

I have an managed object A and managed object A has a many to one relationship with table B.

I set the relationship A to B  by doing something like

```
 Aobject.Bobject=acopyOfB;
```

Which is fine.

I want to write a custom setter for that relationship. This is so I can setup some read only properties in A, based on the value that B gets set to.

So I want to fill in the gap:

```
    -(void) setBobject:(Bobject)theValue{


  'the gap'

  }
```

I am happy with being able to set my custom values, but can't find anywhere the correct syntax for setting the relationship within core data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do something like

```
- (void) setBObject:(BObject*)theValue {
  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"bObject"];
  [self setPrimitiveBObject:theValue];
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"bObject"];

  // Do whatever else you need to do here
}
```

To avoid compiler warnings, you can declare the following before the `@implementation` directive (but in the `.m` file):

```
@interface MyManagedObjectSubClass (PrimitiveAccessors)

@property (nonatomic, retain) BObject* primitiveBObject;

@end
```